# How to calculate sum of nodes, with different number format in xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following XML structure:

```
  <example>
    <data>
       <numberGer>3,40</numberGer>
    </data>
    <data>
      <numberGer>7,40</numberGer>
    </data>
    <data>
       <numberGer>17,40</numberGer>
    </data>
  </example>
```

I need the sum of all the "numberGer" nodes. The formatting of the number is a problem. Because of the use of "," the function "sum" produces a error. So something like sum(//numberGer) does not work. I can use XSLT 2.0 functions.

I think I need to write a recursive template, which takes the computed value and a list of nodes.

Something like:

```
<xsl:template name="addGerNumbers">
        <xsl:param name="number"/>
        <xsl:param name="nodes"/>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$nodes">
          <xsl:variable name="recursive_result">
            ...
           <xsl:call-template name="addGerNumbers">
             ...
            </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:value-of select="$number + $recursive_result"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

At the end I need a single value as an result.

[How to XPath sum() all previous nodes in a XSL for-each loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818804/how-to-xpath-sum-all-previous-nodes-in-a-xsl-for-each-loop) Does not work for me, because I need a single number at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single XPath 2.0 expression is enough:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum( for $i in //numberGer return number(translate( $i, ',','.') ) )"/>
```

The `for` loop will translate each value to replace commas with dots, then convert them into numbers. It returns a sequence of numbers that you can now sum normally.

Comment: Right suggestion but `for` is an `expression` in XPath 2.0, not a `loop`. As an alternative to the `for` expression one could also use `sum(//numberGer/number(translate(., ',', '.')))`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen You've caught me, I'm not a true XPath programmer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using XSLT 2.0, then `sum()` can be easily applied to your input XML. For instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="numbers" as="xs:double*">
            <xsl:for-each select="example/data/numberGer">
                <xsl:sequence select="number(translate(., ',', '.'))"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <result>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum($numbers)"/>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XSLT produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>28.2</result>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Probably the shortest/simplest and most exact XPath 2.0 one-liner**:

```
sum(/*/*/numberGer/xs:decimal(translate(., ',', '.')))
```